# matrix multiplication with Rcpp - different values when the output is assigned

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp

I wrote the following function to calculate a matrix (information matrix of Weibull model)

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

using Eigen::MatrixXd;                  

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]

MatrixXd Weibull_FIM(const vector<double> x, const vector<double> w, const vector<double> param)
{
  if(x.size() != w.size()){
    Rcpp::Rcout<<"The length of x and w is not equal."<<std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  double  a, b, lambda, h, constant;
  a = param[0];
  b = param[1];
  lambda = param[2];
  h = param[3];

  a = a + 0; //just to not get a warning 

  Eigen::MatrixXd Fisher_mat(4, 4);  
  size_t i;

  for(i=0; i < x.size(); i++)
  { 
    constant = exp(-lambda * pow(x[i], h));
    Eigen::MatrixXd f(4, 1);
    f(0, 0) = 1;
    f(1, 0) = -constant;
    f(2, 0) = b*pow(x[i], h)*constant;
    f(3, 0) = b*pow(x[i], h)*constant * lambda * log(x[i]);

    Fisher_mat = w[i] * f * f.transpose() + Fisher_mat;
  }

  return Fisher_mat;
}
```

Now I want to calculate the matrix for some values in R:

```
 Weibull_FIM(x=c(1, 1.239, 1.749371, 5), w = rep(.25, 4), param=c(1, 1, 1, 2))

#            [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]
#[1,]  1.00000000 -0.157545687  0.210509365  0.037774174
#[2,] -0.15754569  0.045985587 -0.053326010 -0.004757122
#[3,]  0.21050936 -0.053326010  0.066320481  0.008736574
#[4,]  0.03777417 -0.004757122  0.008736574  0.002864707
```

This matrix is alright. Now, if I first assign the output and then print it, I will have a different matrix (some of the elements will be changed to some large values!).

```
res <- Weibull_FIM(x=c(1, 1.239, 1.749371, 5), w = rep(.25, 4), param=c(1, 1, 1, 2))
print(res)
#           [,1]           [,2]         [,3]           [,4]
#[1,]  1.00000000  4.727161e+180  0.210509365  2.267126e+161
#[2,] -0.15754569  5.104678e+199 -0.053326010  -4.757122e-03
#[3,]  0.21050936   2.079498e+64  0.066320481   8.736574e-03
#[4,]  0.03777417  -4.757122e-03  0.008736574   2.864707e-03
```

As can be seen, elements (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2) and (3, 2) get another large values.
I would appreciate any help.

Update1 in response to @Ronald:

- version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
- Windows 7 x64
- platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
- Rcpp_0.11.3, RcppEigen_0.3.2.3.0, tools_3.1.2
- Rtools version 3.2.0.1948

Comment: You should provide your system information. I can reproduce this using R 3.2.0 with newest package versions on a Win7 system with an older version of Rtools (I need our system admin for updating). I cannot reproduce this on a linux system with R 3.1.2 and the newest package versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `Fisher_mat` with zeroes before summation, so it sometimes may contain random junk. Adding e.g. `Fisher_mat.setZero();` before a `for` loop will give you a consistent output.

Check this reference: [RcppEigen Introduction](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppEigen/vignettes/RcppEigen-Introduction.pdf).

Comment: Add the line I propose and the result will be correct both times (I checked that on a very similar setup).

Comment: Thank u,  the result is consistent now.But if I dont set it then the Fisher_mat contain very small numbers (like 1.780215e-306) and in R 1.780215e-306 + .001 = .001 and  1.780215e-306 - .001 = -.001. Ok let suppose there was precision problem. But my main question is why (Weibull_FIM(x=c(1, 1.239, 1.749371, 5), w = rep(.25, 4), param=c(1, 1, 1, 2))) gives me the right answer but this one is not (res <- Weibull_FIM(x=c(1, 1.239, 1.749371, 5), w = rep(.25, 4), param=c(1, 1, 1, 2))) 
your response solved my problem (one up) but I keep waiting for the reason (before adding your line).

Comment: @EhsanMasoudi It might contain these numbers under specific circumstances, but these circumstances are not guaranteed to be reproducible. It's certainly not related to precision.

Comment: @Roland is absolutely correct. Initialization of `Fisher_mat` in this case just allocates the memory and does not guarantee all entries to be zero as you are probably expecting. What you get is exactly "random junk".

Comment: @Ronald and tonytonov you are right.
I did not set the Fisher_mat to zero becasue I thought it had the same behaviour as NumericMatrix in Rcpp.
// Matrix of 4 rows & 5 columns (filled with 0)
NumericMatrix xx(4, 5);
but it does not.

Comment: Nope, we do explicitly set memory to zero and still consider that to be the correct (and safe) default.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel but when I only return the initialized Fisher_mat I will have a matrix that all of the elements are very small (1e-308) and not exact zeros (for NumericMatrix I have exact zeros).

Comment: Which is what I said. Rcpp sets elements to zero, RcppEigen does not because Eigen does not.